# Script to reset user password (HP-UX)

Tags: shell, hp-ux, passwd

I am trying to write a shell script to reset a user password. It will accept 2 arguments, 1 old password and the new password.

I have used expect and the script works. However, my tech folks do not allow me to install expect in the production servers.

Any suggestions on how to script this?

I tried the methods suggested by this article but it does not work:
http://en.kioskea.net/faq/790-changing-password-via-a-script

Comment: Have you noted that the solutions found in that link are not for HP-UX but for Linux? I guess the `password` command for HP-UX will not accept the option `--stdin`.

Comment: Yeap I realised that as well. Just to put it out there....

Comment: You need something like `expect` to provide a pseudo-terminal for password input. If folks do not allow you to install `expect`, you could write a C program like that yourself. Would you be allowed to install such a self-written program?